# Why can't I change a list in a method?

Tags: python

I have a method that contains no loops.  I pass a list into that method. I assign the list a new value per this snippet:

```
def do_paging(pageable_list):
    pageable_list = pageable_list[start:end]
```

In the calling code:

```
do_paging(source_list)
```

but it does not look like the `source_list` gets changed. If I return `pageable_list` from `do_paging()` everything is great. Are array arguments immutable?

I started returning the value because it's better. But I am surprised and would like to know what's going on.

EDIT - how could I have been programming Python for a year and not known this!

Comment: Arguments in Python are always passed by value. You're just shadowing the argument by defining a new `pageable_list` name.

Comment: You aren't modifying the list, you are creating a new list. To modify the list you must modify the list. For example, `pageable_list.append("something")` will modify the list.

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/2670792

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: Also note that modifying a passed mutable is usually a bad idea. Instead, return a new mutable with the changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slicing is creating a new list:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a[1:2]
>>> a is b
False
```

You are not mutating the original list:

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Furthermore, you are never doing anything with the list you assign the name `pageable_list` to in your `do_paging` function.

So the problems are a) you don't modify the original list and/or b) you don't return anything from your function. One way to make your code work is to create the slice and reassign the name `pageable_list` to the return value of your function, i.e.:

```
def do_paging(pageable_list, start, end):
    return pageable_list[start:end]

pageable_list = do_paging(pageable_list, start, end)
```

The function should probably take `start` and `end` arguments as well, looking for those in the global space is kind of ugly.

However, if all you need your function to do is the slicing, the function is not really useful, you could just use the line

```
pageable_list = pageable_list[start:end]
```

Comment: `start` and `end` are in the method. I posted a snippet.

Comment: @TonyEnnis alright, then you don't need those extra arguments

Comment: I agree that a method is a bit heavyweight for this task.  However, there is a simple way to mutate a list in a method in the way the OP wants using slice assignment: `pageable_list[:] = pageable_list[start:end]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski we have an answer using this method in here, I'm sure OP has seen it.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed this method below when I was recently reviewing [code from Quantopian](https://www.quantopian.com/help#using-results) and had never it used before.  Per the comment from @Steven_Rumbalski, this is assigning the slice back to the input variable `pageable_list`.

```
def do_paging(pageable_list, start, end):
    pageable_list[:] = pageable_list[start:end]

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

do_paging(a, 2, 4)

>>> a
[3, 4]
```

Comment: The term you are looking for is *slice assignment*.  It has nothing to do with pointers and variables.  Rather, `pageable_list[:] = pageable_list[start:end]` is syntactic sugar for calling the mutating method `pageable_list.__setslice__`.

Comment: Indeed, as `a = 1` and `a[:] = 3` returns the error `TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment`.  Thanks for the education.

Answer (score 2):

You're not changing "the list". You're assigning a new value to a local variable.

Mutating the list itself would work:

```
def do_paging(pageable_list):
    pageable_list.pop()
```

But the variable `pageable_list` is merely a local variable and assigning some new value to it does not modify the value which was previously assigned to it.